# How to recover/reset password on Ascend/Lucent SuperPipe 155

Tags: router

I am trying to set up an Ascend/Lucent SuperPipe 155 ISDN router that I don't know the password to. I need to recover or reset this password before I can use the router. I found a reset procedure [on a tek-tips thread](https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=407007), but it did not work when I tried it on mine.

The NINDY (bootloader) code on my unit seems to be a bit different than what is described in that thread, despite being the same model of router. The thread references an "EF" (erase flash) command, but that option does not show up in mine. The only similar option on mine is "EP" (menu description: erase program area). Running EP does seem to erase the OS from the unit's flash memory (although apparently not the configuration, including passwords). Attempting to run EF does nothing:

```
SuperPipe Platform - 1300-0290-001


   Boot Rom Version 9


bg      Boot program from flash
cf      Check flash
df      Download program to flash then boot
ep      Erase program area
mt      Memory test
?       Help
h       Help


SPIPE>EF

SPIPE>
```

After erasing the program area, I can install various versions of the OS using the DF command, but the configuration and password remain in place even after downgrading to 7.4.2 and then upgrading back to 9.1-144.1 or 9.1-144.3 as mentioned in the thread.

Do any of you remember working with these and have any other ideas I could try?